# Efficient set union and intersection in C++

Tags: python, c++, set

Given two sets set1 and set2, I need to compute the ratio of their intersection by their union. So far, I have the following code:

```
double ratio(const set<string>& set1, const set<string>& set2)
{
    if( set1.size() == 0 || set2.size() == 0 )
        return 0;

    set<string>::const_iterator iter;
    set<string>::const_iterator iter2;
    set<string> unionset;

    // compute intersection and union
    int len = 0;
    for (iter = set1.begin(); iter != set1.end(); iter++) 
    {
        unionset.insert(*iter);
        if( set2.count(*iter) )
            len++;
    }
    for (iter = set2.begin(); iter != set2.end(); iter++) 
        unionset.insert(*iter);

    return (double)len / (double)unionset.size();   
}
```

It seems to be very slow (I'm calling the function about 3M times, always with different sets). The python counterpart, on the other hand, is way much faster

```
def ratio(set1, set2):
    if not set1 or not set2:
        return 0
    return len(set1.intersection(set2)) / len(set1.union(set2))
```

Any idea about how to improve the C++ version (possibly, not using Boost)?

Comment: There is `std::set_union` and `std::set_intersection`. Have you tried with that ?

Comment: Maybe you should look at how the python sets are implemented in C++? https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules

Comment: according to the documentation it requires sorted ranges. It looks like it should take more

Comment: How big are these strings? Your C++ code performs a lot of string copies that your Python code doesn't. (Also, C++'s `std::set` is a BST and Python's `set` is a hash table, so that would cause differences.)

Comment: not that big. definitely less than 100

Comment: Here is the precise module from the standard lib https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/setobject.c

Comment: @user60143: Less than 100 what?

Comment: definitely less than 100 items per set

Comment: @user60143: No, how big are the *strings*?

Comment: the max size is around 10 characters

Comment: would it make a big difference to reduce the size of the strings?

Comment: @user2357112 you are right. Count() is logarithmic in size.

Comment: I reduced the size of the strings. No difference in performance. I'm wondering if using sets of integers would make any difference then.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in linear time, without new memory:

```
double ratio(const std::set<string>& set1, const std::set<string>& set2)
{
    if (set1.empty() || set2.empty()) {
        return 0.;
    }
    std::set<string>::const_iterator iter1 = set1.begin();
    std::set<string>::const_iterator iter2 = set2.begin();
    int union_len = 0;
    int intersection_len = 0;
    while (iter1 != set1.end() && iter2 != set2.end()) 
    {
        ++union_len;
        if (*iter1 < *iter2) {
            ++iter1;
        } else if (*iter2 < *iter1) {
            ++iter2;
        } else { // *iter1 == *iter2
            ++intersection_len;
            ++iter1;
            ++iter2;
        }
    }
    union_len += std::distance(iter1, set1.end());
    union_len += std::distance(iter2, set2.end());
    return static_cast<double>(intersection_len) / union_len;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to construct the union set. In Python terms, `len(s1.union(s2)) == len(s1) + len(s2) - len(s1.intersection(s2))`; the size of the union is the sum of the sizes of `s1` and `s2`, minus the number of elements counted twice, which is the number of elements in the intersection. Thus, you can do

```
for (const string &s : set1) {
    len += set2.count(s);
}
return ((double) len) / (set1.size() + set2.size() - len)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I just thought about that. It seems to be slightly faster. However, the python version is still significantly faster.